# Modifying `date` format to have "2nd"/"3rd"/etc. using case statement and/or regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that'll output the date in this format: `Friday, May 2nd`. This is part of an assignment that calls for using each of a regex, a `case` statement, and `sed` to modify the output of the `date` command into the desired format.

I'm starting from the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
date "+%A, %B %d"
```

...but output is of the form:

```
Friday, May 2
```

not the needed form of:

```
Friday, May 2nd
```

Comment: show what you have and what's the problem

Comment: why do you need a regex to do this, you can just do this `date '+%A, %B %d'` and that should output the date in your format. However might have to add some logic to add in st, nd, rd, th etc.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yeah I know I have already done it that way echo "Welcome $(whoami) today is, $(date +'%A, %B %d')" | sed' '

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I updated it with a little of what I have, I have already done one script but practicing regexs and cases so trying to do my script using cases regexs and Sed

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah but I still don't understand how I can do this with a regex

Comment: Regex does not naturally fit into this problem, that might be why. Date formatting isn't really a pattern matching problem.

Comment: Yea I know it doesnt make sense and that is why I am confused. This is an assignment to use regex/sed to output Hello user, today is (date) I am not looking for the answer just help, because I don't get it I have already wrote a script that works for the output but that is not sufficient for this assignment

Comment: the hint he gave was to use the case statement

Comment: Write a shell script that greets the user in this format hello userName today is Wednesday April 20 where username is the user account from the command whoami. get date information from date command, but it needs formatting. in particular, aside from pulling apart the individual pieces of the date, you will need to expand the name of the day of the week and month in full normal forms; date command only returns abbreviations. hint:case statement will be of use here. the script should work not only for wednesday/april. use sed command and appropriate regex to extract info from date

Comment: Ahh -- so what they want you to do is get `date` in the wrong format, and then tear it apart and piece it back together, instead of asking the `date` command to give it to you in the right format in the first place. *sigh*; at least it makes sense now. (BTW, including that description in the question itself might have led to less confusion earlier)

Answer (score 1):

It is an odd requirement. Here's how you'd use `case` to add the [ordinal suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator#Other_suffixes)

```
d=$(date '+%A, %B %e')
case $d in 
    *1[0-9]) d+=th ;; 
    *1) d+=st ;; 
    *2) d+=nd ;; 
    *3) d+=rd ;; 
    *)  d+=th ;; 
esac
echo "Welcome $(whoami) today is, $d"
```

Note that `case` does not use regular expressions, it uses [shell patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: You're welcome. Normally, we expect the asker to do more research but I got the feeling you were completely blocked.

Comment: Also, it is important to understand the difference between regular expressions and shell glob patterns.

Comment: Thanks can you please explain?

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glob) in your quest for enlightenment.

Comment: alright thanks and as far as the reg ex goes for this question do you have any tips

Comment: My tip: explain to your teacher that they aren't required for this task. I'm often reminded of this saying: "When your only tool is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." Regular expressions are a powerful tool, but just a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` to apply a series of replacements (conditional on regular expressions matching) might look like:

```
d=$(date '+%A, %B %e')

d_sed=$(sed -Ee 's/(1[0-9])$/\1th/' \
             -e 's/1$/1st/' \
             -e 's/2$/2nd/' \
             -e 's/3$/3rd/' \
             -e 's/([[:digit:]])$/\1th/' <<<"$d")

echo "Welcome $(whoami), today is $d_sed"
```

In this, each expression such as `(.*1[0-9])$` is a regex. (Using the `-E` argument enables the "POSIX extended" regular expression syntax, which is significantly easier to work with than BRE, the "basic" POSIX regex syntax).

Breaking down the syntax used in those regular expressions:

- `[0-9]` defines a *character class* that matches a single character anywhere between `0` and `9`. This particular one could also be written as `[[:digit:]]`, one of the predefined classes.
- `$` means "match only if the end of the line falls at this position", so `3$` matches only if a `3` is the last character in a line.
- `(...)` treats the contents of the parenthesis as a group. This means that operators like `*` and `+` treat that group as a unit, but also (for our purposes) acts as a capture operator: `\1` on the replacement side refers back to the first *capture group*, thus, the content that was found within those parens.

Comment: ohhh ok that makes more sense I am going to put this into a script and try it out!

Comment: would this be similar using awk

Comment: It *could* be written similarly using `awk`. For instance, `awk '/1[0-9]$/ { print $0 "th" } /1$/ { print $0 "st" } /2$/ { print $0 "nd" }'` will handle the first three cases (and hopefully is a good enough hint to let you write the rest). The content in the slashes, like `1[0-9]$`, are a pattern -- treated as a regex -- and the content in the curly braces afterwards are the code that gets run if that regex matches the current line. (Awk allows other, non-regex kinds of patterns; it's specifically patterns that are just content within slashes that are treated as regular expressions).